# How can I get around this Windows/SQL Server/Visual Studio versions headache?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

I know the answer to the question is... "Upgrade the W7 machine", but I know that in some instances of where my app will be deployed, this is not an option, so I'm looking for a workaround.

I have built my first C# windows form application using Visual Studio 2022. It uses a local database.

The app is a simple CSV file reader / scraper that piles all of the CSV data into a local database and then gives the user the data in a user friendly format with charts etc. It will be deployed at various sites around the country, mostly in a single-user type installation.

Everything works fine on my Windows 11 machine that I've used to develop it.

When I install on a test windows 7 machine, I get an error similar to

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 782 and earlier.

What I have learned from Google searching:

- I can't install SQL Server 2019 (which as far as I can tell, is what I need) on windows 7.
- It's not possible to 'downgrade' the database from within my visual studio project.
- There may be a method to script the database creation from within my app.

Is there a workaround, and also, how can I test on Windows 10 if I don't have a machine available?

Many thanks

I have tried adjusting the 'Compatibility level' from within VS2022, no change

Comment: Does it have to be localdb? Could you maybe use sqlite instead since that isn't tied to what is installed on the machine?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be local dB. I just guessed early on that a local database would be sufficient for a simple app like this. Would would be involved in changing it now, and what are the main differences?

Comment: If you are using entity framework (or another ORM) the changes needed would be quite small. You could probably just switch out with database provider/adapter you are using. If you are doing raw SQL you might need to adjust your queries if you are using sql server specific functions.

Comment: You could install SQL LocalDB 2014 or SQL Server 2014 on your local machine, and refer to that duting your build. That will be compatible with those machines (which really should be upgraded pronto). Note that Compatibility level has nothing to do with it, that's forward compatibility, not backwards compatibility. It is otherwise impossible to use a newer versioned DB on an older system.

Comment: Win 7's _Mainstream Support_ ended in Jan 2015, and it went _End of Life_ in Jan 2020. Supporting your product on an out of support OS is asking for trouble (in particular it is a security risk). Ypu should work to remove Win7 from your supported OS list

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use sqlite or just a memory array